# How does one obtain a Witcher 3 Troll Mutagen from a non-quest specific troll, at least one of which you never exchange dialogue with?

Tags: the-witcher-3

I have played the Witcher 3, exchanged dialogue with 5 trolls already, and decided not to kill them. All 5 trolls were involved in specific quests. I have killed two trolls of which I did not exchange dialogue. I have yet to receive a Troll Mutagen.

How does one obtain a Witcher 3 Troll Mutagen from a non-quest specific troll, at least one of which you never exchange dialogue with?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The best way to get one is from the rabid rock troll on An Skellige. It spawns next to the fast travel point Trail to Yngvar's Fang which is Northeast of Urialla Harbor. It respawns, i got my mutagen after 5 kills.

Comment: What is the re-spawn rate?

Comment: I tried meditating for several days in a troll cave in Velen and nothing happened.

Comment: I do not know the re-spawn rate.

Comment: I traveled to your suggested location and I have yet to observer the trolls respawn. What should I do?

Comment: Fast travel to Urialla harbor then ride to Trail to Yngvars Fang. It respawned immediately for me.

Comment: I ended up fast-traveling to the Trail point and the troll was there. Saving before killing it and reloading if no mutagen drops is the way to go.