# What must I do to force troll respawn in Witcher 3?

Tags: the-witcher-3

I am having trouble collecting my first troll mutagen in Witcher 3. I have found several trolls in the game, but none of them have dropped a single troll mutagen. I have received advise from others to re-kill the trolls by saving the game and reloading it. I have tried this several times, and none of my trolls re-spawned. In fact, when I revisit locations where trolls were slain, they never reappear. I am unsure if this is a bug in the pc version or something else.

What must I do to force troll respawn in Witcher 3?

Comment: [how to obtain a troll mutagen](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/222922/how-does-one-obtain-a-witcher-3-troll-mutagen-from-a-non-quest-specific-troll-a?rq=1)

Comment: This is not a duplicate question. The previous question asked about how to receive a specific item from an npc. This question asks about how to force a npc respawn. Plus, my comment in the previous question was not fully addressed, so I asked this question.

Answer (score 0):

Some says that a mysterious (and stupid) monster lives in an island in the north of Kaer Morhen, it might require your expertise, Witcher.

Missing : miners near Blandare in Ard Skellig. Local people are wondering why some silver veins roar.

Comment: Doesn't Kaer Morhen become available only after main quest leads you there? Hunt for troll mutagen would suggest being before that point. Though it IS good to know I missed something there

Comment: I didn't had any troll mutagen at this point of the game, and I didn't rushed  the main quest at all